# How to handle a Java 7 LWJGL shader exception?

Tags: macos, java-7, lwjgl, jmonkeyengine

I try and run my [techdemo](https://sourceforge.net/projects/spaceworld/) for a 3D rendering using the 3d engine jme3 and the jmeplanet library and it displays the startup splash screen and starts rendering the 3D scene but when starting the control and actually move around in the gameworld, it crashes with this error msg. Can you help me interpret what it means? The projects runs ok on MS-Windows 8.1 (but it also gets a second different stacktrace on Ubuntu).

[image]

Comment: This is an issue with your fragment shader (piece of code that runs on the graphics card). Have you attempted to edit the fragment shader? If so could you include it in the question (with the corresponding j3md material file)

Comment: Btw the most likely reason for different errors on different computers will be due to differing fragment shaders for different OpenGL versions; it is likely only 1 is broken

Comment: Have you updated to the latest graphics drivers yet ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the error, it looks like the OpenGL was unable to compile your fragment shader, since the error specifies that the GLSL language version is 1 (language=GLSL100) which is very old, I assume the syntax used to creating the shader is meant for a higher level of OpenGL. Try to see what OpenGL version the engine is using and if is supported by your graphics card. Also, try to check if the source code of that fragment shader contains `#version XXXX` directive at the first line, if it doesn't try to add the GLSL version of the OpenGL version the engine is using.

If it didn't solved your problem please post here the source code of that fragment shader.

Comment: I found where to be explicit about OpenGL version in `AppSettings.java` and now I'm going to try it next time I got another os than Win 8.1. I'm also testing it with emulated Ubuntu in Virtuabox where it gets a different stacktrace.

Comment: I think on an emulated OS there must be some options to enable hardware acceleration (opengl, directx, etc .. ). Make sure it enabled there before testing